# How do I put the required attribute on my inputs using jade?

Tags: pug

I want to do this in jade:

```
 <input type='text' name='example' required>
```

I cant find a way to add the required attribute using jade. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 4):

```
input(type='text', name='example', required)
```

or if it depends on a variable

```
- var isRequired = true
input(type='text', name='example', required=isRequired)
```

Note that the required attribute is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Note that this actually outputs `<input type="text" name="example" required="required"/>`.  Not sure if there is a real-world difference between `required="required"` and `required`, though.